# ListIterator Strange Adding to ArrayList

Tags: java, linked-list, listiterator

I have the following code:

```
    ArrayList<String> words;
    words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.add("is");
    words.add("us");
    ListIterator<String> it;
    it = words.listIterator();
    it.add("##");
    System.out.println(words);
    it.next();
    it.next();
    it.previous();
    it.set("##");
    System.out.println(words);
```

I would expect that the output would be `## us ##`, but when I run the program it returns `## is ##`. I expect that this has to do with the `ListIterator` adding an item to the `ArrayList` instead of the `ArrayList` adding an item to its self.

Why does the program behave in this way?

Comment: Your program is *much* more complicated than it needs to be, with both an `add` and a `set`, as well as moving next and previous. It's not clear *why* you'd expect the result of "## us ##".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but I suspect the main point you may be missing is that `ListIterator.add` inserts at the current location:

> The element is inserted immediately before the next element that would be returned by next(), if any, and after the next element that would be returned by previous(), if any.

And also:

> The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to next would be unaffected

So after your initial call to `it.add("##")` the list contains `"##"`, `"is"` `"us"`. You're then moving next twice - the first moves the cursor to just after `"is"` (which is returned). The second moves the cursor to just after `"us"` (which is returned). Then the call to `previous()` returns `"us"` again, and finally a call to `set()` replaces `"us"` with `"##"`:

> Replaces the last element returned by next() or previous() with the specified element (optional operation).

It all looks like it's obeying the documentation perfectly. Unfortunately it's not clear which of these steps is confusing you, as you've conflated so many in one question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I apologize for the lack of specificity in my question. This chunk of code was a sample from my CS class, which (as you have mentioned) as an intense compulsion to overcomplicate code. I included the entire snippet just to be sure I didn't accidentally exclude a line that could make it return the result that it did. Thanks again.